# Command to press a button

Tags: evaluation, dynamic, warning-messages, system, button

Under normal circumstances, giving a command to

> press the `Button`

is stupid. Because we only need to execute the **button action of that `Button`**.

But under some circumstances, `a button action alone` doesn't work, it makes an warning message.
With a little surprise, if we put `the button action alone` into a mathematica `Button`, and click that `Button`, it works.

So I am trying to find way to `command to press a Button`.

Can you make a command, when executed, it presses following button :

```
Button["Click Here", Print[10!]]
```

I believe that

**the more independent** `act of pressing a button` is from `action of the button`,

**the higher the chance of success.**

In Huber's case, it failed because it approached the button's action **too directly**.

## Here is the motivation of this question :

[Save as custom folder succeeded! But in two steps](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297619/save-as-custom-folder-succeeded-but-in-2-steps)

Comment: What warning message? Don't you want to fix the cause of the problem|?

Comment: @Kuba ♦: Yes, I updated the question. You can check it in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297619/save-as-custom-folder-succeeded-but-in-2-steps

Answer (score 3):

Conside:

```
but = Button["Click Here", Print[10!]];
but // FullForm
```

[image]

As yiou can see, the button action is the second element in "but". Therefore, to evaluate it, you can simply write:

```
but[[2]];

3628800
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work.  I believe it failed because it approached the button's action too directly. For more : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297619/save-as-custom-folder-succeeded-but-in-two-steps