# Save as custom folder in menu bar in 1 step

Tags: function-construction, front-end, evaluation, warning-messages, system

I found the solution for myself.

For some reasons I decided to write the updated content(=solution) at the top. One important reason is.. that  you almost don't need to read after the solution.

`Solution` :

Find the file `MenuSetup.tr`, open it with text editor, and add

```
MenuItem["Save as (custom version)", 
KernelExecute[NotebookSave[InputNotebook[], SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "C:\\myfile.nb"]]], 
 MenuEvaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Queued"],
```

after the existing line

```
MenuItem["Save", "MenuListSaveItems", MenuAnchor->True],
```

## You almost don't need to read from here :

I've succeeded to create `save as.. with custom initial folder`, **but in 2 steps**.

Please follow the instruction (not dangerous unless you backup MenuSetup.tr):

Open a notebook(.nb)

Take a snapshot of menubar file tab :

[image]

Type

```
CustomSaveAs =
 Button["Click Here", 
  NotebookSave[InputNotebook[], 
   SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "C:\\myfile.nb"]], 
  Rule[Method, "Queued"]]
```

and execute. You see a button is created, the button is for `save as.. with custom initial folder`.
You can test the button.(click it)

Back up your original `MenuSetup.tr`.
It is located at
`Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\**version number**\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\MenuSetup.tr`

Open the file `MenuSetup.tr` with text editor. After the line

```
MenuItem["Save", "MenuListSaveItems", MenuAnchor->True],
```

add following lines :

```
 MenuItem["Save as (custom version)", 
 KernelExecute[CreateDialog[CustomSaveAs]], 
 MenuEvaluator -> Automatic],
```

Now back to the notebook. Type

```
FrontEndExecute@{FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[], 
ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic, Automatic}]};
```

and execute. It immediately updates the menubar. Take a snapshot of menubar file tab :

[image]

(Save as (custome version) added)

Now click `save as (custom version)` in the menubar. Then a button pops up. Click the button. Then you see save as window with custom initial folder.

We succeeded to implement `save as with custom initial folder` finally, **but it needs 2 steps**.

Click 'save as (custom version)' in a menubar,
then click the `Click Here` button.

With a little surprise, if we put the button action directly in the MenuSetup.tr, we get a following warning messages :

```
SystemDialogInput::nprmtv:   
SystemDialogInput is not currently supported within preemptive evaluations.
```

Of course, **my final goal** is to see `save as window with custom initial folder`, with a **single** click. Just **one step**.
A workaround may be.. writing down a command to press the button in the `MenuSetup.tr`.
But I don't know the command to press a button. For more :

[Command to press a button](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297563/command-to-press-a-button)

[Change default save path/location of an .nb by code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297459/change-default-save-path-location-of-an-nb-by-code)

Comment: What is it good for when you can save notebook in any directory you want and with any name you want with a one line code with `NotebookSave`?

Comment: It's complicated to explain, but to explain briefly, all of my questions recently are ultimately aimed at improving the functionality of `Hyperlink`. When you move to a new document via a hyperlink ***in a existing window***, the default save location should also change.

Comment: When you move to the new document then you can use `NotebookSave` with desired path which changes also default path of `Save as...` to the same path. So if you then use `Save as...` it will be used with the desired path so I do not understand your cumbersome method when one function do the same and even better.

Comment: In fact.. For smooth screen transitions, only the contents of the new document will be loaded from the existing window frame. Therefore, strictly speaking, it is not moved to a new document, but the contents of the new document are visible in the existing window.

Comment: And to explain more, for current `Hyperlink` system, if a document is already open, this document cannot be opened repeatedly through a hyperlink. Therefore, we have no choice but to approach this thorny path.

Comment: It's an issue with a complex story, so I can understand.. Most of you will wonder why I'm so obsessed with such small problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default save path/location of an .nb by code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297459/change-default-save-path-location-of-an-nb-by-code)

Comment: No, because that question is not resolved.